# z-order of a matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I added a color bar to my plot using

```
cb = matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar()
```

And also, I added annotations.
The annotations are obscured by the color bar.
The color bar does not have a zorder property I can set, it seems.
How do I make them appear behind the annotations?

[image]

Comment: change the zorder of the main Axes or the colorbar Axes.  (`cb.ax.zorder = -1`).  mpl draws axes at a time so you need to change the axes zorder to control overlap between axes.   It is best to post runnable examples.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was trying cb.zorder = x without the '.ax' part. If you write it as answer, I will mark it as such.